# Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on the server

Tags: php, android, api, connection, wampserver

This is the error that I get when I try to access the PC from my phone.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your apache.conf file

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/yourwebroot">
    AllowOverride All 
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and restart your apache2 server

The access control configuration changed in 2.4, and old configurations aren't compatible without some changes. See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html).

If your old config was Allow from all (no IP addresses blocked from accessing the service), then Require all granted is the new functional equivilent.

Comment: The `W` in WAMPServer stands for `W`indows

Comment: And it would be much more secure to do `Require ip 192.168.254` rather than open up to the universe